# Multiplication of Projection/Hat matrix and diagonal matrix of positive entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $H$ be the hat/projection matrix that is symmetric and positive semidefinite and $D$ be a diagonal matrix with a diagonal of ones except the last term being greater than 1. If we partition these matrices in blocks we can say

$D= \begin{bmatrix}1&0&...&&\\0&1&0&... \\  & &1&... \\  \\ 0 &0&0&0&e>1\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I\end{bmatrix}&\begin{bmatrix}0\end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}0\end{bmatrix}&e\end{bmatrix}$ and $ H = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix}&\begin{bmatrix}C\end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}C^T\end{bmatrix}&b\end{bmatrix}$ where C is a row vector and b is a scalar.

so

$ DH = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A\end{bmatrix}&\begin{bmatrix}C\end{bmatrix}\\e\begin{bmatrix}C^T\end{bmatrix}&e\times b\end{bmatrix}$

The product DH will not be symmetrical but can we say anything about the truth of the following statement

$x^T DH x > 0$

where $x$ is a vector with all non-negative entries. I can't prove it's positive semidefinite from the beggining because the matrix is not symmetric. I thought maybe using Schur complements with these block matrices could work but I have not found any definitions for non symmetric matrices.

H is psd by definition. We can use the definitions of psd with the schur complement and state that $A\geq0$ and also  $b - C^TA^{-1}C \geq 0$.

If we can use the same definition for the matrix DH(probably we can't because it's not symmetric) we know that $A>0$ and hence if $eb - eC^TA^{-1}C \geq 0$ the matrix is psd. Since e is a scalar bigger than 1 we see that the condition holds and we could proove that the matrix is psd.

Edit 1 - Edited to positive semidefinite

Edit 2 - Edited to have more information

Edit 3 - Proposal of a proof

Comment: "Let  be the hat/projection matrix that is symmetric and positive definite"... then $H =I$.  Positive definite matrices are invertible, and its standard (and short) exercise that the only invertible idempotent element is the identity.  Once you allow $H$ to be singular then the quadratic form could equal zero i.e. if $\mathbf x $ in the kernel of $H$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected my statement. It should say H is positive semidefinite. It is given by the formula $H = B (B^T B)^{-1}B^T$ where B can be any matrix.

Comment: ok so you're asking, is $\mathbf x^T DH \mathbf x\geq  0$...  I know the Hat matrix -- it is very cute that it 'puts a hat on observed values... also note $B$ can't be *any* matrix... it must be injective (i.e. all columns linearly independent) for that expression to be valid.  This may still be a dead end, but I'd start with symmetrization, i.e. consider instead $Z:= DH + HD$  (sometimes we'd but a scalar of $\frac{1}{2}$ in there but it isn't really helpful here); the fact that $\mathbf x$ is non-negative and so is $D$ is somewhat interesting

Comment: 2 more things, (i) since $H$ is orthogonally diagonalizable (and similar to a matirx that is blocked identity $I_r$ in top right and everything else zero, where r is the rank of $H$  with $U$ consider $B:= U^T Z U$.  A positive semidefinite matrix can only have zeros on the diagonal element k if all of row k and col k are 0 but $B$ has a blocks of zeros on the diagonal.  (ii) do you really want to know if this is psd?  The case $\mathbf x^T B \mathbf x \geq 0$ for all $\mathbf x \geq 0$ is called being *copositive* (copositive programming is NP Hard in general)

Comment: Yes, not any matrix. $B$ is indeed injective in my case. What I need to know is if the product $x^TDHx$ is strictly positive. Moreover I added some specificity to the question that may help clarify. I will try your symmetrization also.

Comment: Also I don't understand in your example how you can have Z, which is not a diagonal matrix between $U^T$ and $U$,

Comment: I may have done that comment too late at night and skipped a step, $H$ is othogonally diagonalizable as $H= U\Lambda U^T$  so I did an orthgonal similarity transform to $Z$, that's all.

Comment: Oh ok! I see. Although I have two more questions. How can I test a matrix foi copositivity since this is all I need? Also if you could recomend me a book on this I would really appreciate it since I'm not a mathematician and I'm a bit out of my depth here. Also you say that H is blocked identity in top right and everything else is zero.  This is not what I observe for my case. I don't understand what you mean with this.

Comment: what I said was " is orthogonally diagonalizable (and *similar* to a matrix that is blocked identity $I_r$ in top right..." -- I didn't say it *is* $I_r$ in top right.  This assumes you understand similarity transform and the standard form for diagonalization -- any other form will be the same up to permutation similarity, but standard form is preferred for hopefully obvious reasons.  As for copositive programming, look it's NP-Hard in general which means it won't scale well.  The only books I've run into it are re: semidefinite programming books and I don't know any accessible SDP books.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I don't really understand about similarity transforms, As I was saying this is 1really new to me. The cases I work usually are normal symmetrical psd. Nonetheless I followed your advice to symmetrize. Indeed using Schur complements I can prove that the symmetrized matrix Z is psd provided e is less than $\sqrt(2)-1$. Also the skew symmetric TH-HT has a 0 on the last diagonal element

Comment: Some interesting ideas, and FWIW Schur Complements aren't all that easy to work through, so good job.  It belatedly occurs to me that there's more structure in your $D$ (i.e. its an elementary matrix of the third type) so I think I can get to a result like yours via a simpler path-- I'll submit it as an answer if I find something nice enough

Comment: Thanks a lot and thank you for your interest and the time you dedicated. Importantly, using numerical examples and playing on wolfram I've been able to see that the matrix $DH$ is in fact not psd. If I take e = 1.5 and a x with some negative elements I get $x^T DH x <0$.  I have not been able to find one example of this with positive elements in x though.

Comment: Also for what is worth i expect $x^TDHx $ to be upper bounded by $x^TDx $ and have been verifying this with numerical examples.